# read file line by line and store different variables

Tags: c++, readfile

My text file look like this:

```
1     52    Hayden Smith        18:16   15  M   Berlin
2     54    Mark Puleo          18:25   15  M   Berlin
3     97    Peter Warrington    18:26   29  M   New haven
4     305   Matt Kasprzak       18:53   33  M   Falls Church
5     272   Kevin Solar         19:17   16  M   Sterling
6     394   Daniel Sullivan     19:35   26  M   Sterling
7     42    Kevan DuPont        19:58   18  M   Boylston
8     306   Chris Goethert      20:00   43  M   Falls Church
9     262   James Sullivan      20:12   28  M   Sterling
10    348   Bill Gaudere        20:17   54  M   Hudson
11    13    Travis Wheeler      20:23   31  M   Clinton
12    69    Eric Anderson       20:34   54  M   Clinton
13    341   Alex Teixeira       20:46   0   M   Clinton
14    112   James Long          20:50   38  M   0
15    279   Nate Richards       21:31   17  M   Berlin
......................................................
```

There are eight columns, separated by 'tabs', except the first name and last name is separated by a space.

I must have eight different types of variables.

```
    int a;
    int b;
    string c;
    string d;
    string e;
    int f;
    char g;
    string h;
```

I need to read the file line by line and cout every line's a, b, c, d, e, f.
I also need those variables for later use.

So, I tried this:

```
std::ifstream infile("text.txt");
int a;
int b;
string c;
string d;
string e;
int f;
char g;
string h;


while(infile>>a>>b>>c>>d>>e>>f>>g>>h)
{
    cout <<"C is: "<<c<<endl;   // just to see if the loop is working.

}
```

I don't need arrays and vectors to store those variables, I have a linked structure. Right now, I just need a way to read the file and store those strings and integers into variables. 
But it's not working, lol. Don't know why. I also thought about using getline, something like this:

```
while(getline(infield, s)):
```

But, isn't this essentially just giving me one big fat line, with all strings and integers smashed together.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if you can do that all in one line, but I would advise against it. With each entry you read in, there is a possibility for error(e.g. incorrect type). I would think you'd want to write code(or at least debug code) that checks for the errors. Besides, it doesn't really give a whole lot of performance gain doing it in one expression as opposed to doing it in multiple expressions.

Comment: Treating that file format as eight columns is a big problem with your approach. Someone's going to input names like "Lee Harvey Oswald" or "Barrack Hussein Obama" in there to kill your program. No, there's a reason there is no tab between first name and second name, and the reason is that they should be considered as one column. Incidentally, this then also works with New Haven. BTW: The family of file formats is called CSV, even though it's a tab not a comma here, and you should find sufficiend info online about parsing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach works exactly as you want it to when testing it on my machine, except for the fact that it will stop at the third entry:

```
3     97    Peter Warrington    18:26   29  M   New haven
```

This is because of the space in `New haven`, which will fail the while condition as it fails to be copied into the integer field, `a` on the next iteration. If you want to keep this structure, perhaps put underscores in place of spaces. Otherwise move to parsing it line by line, perhaps with the `std::regex` library.

For example, changing the location string to be seperated by underscores instead of spaces results in finding all 15 entries. To change the underscores back into spaces we can use `std::replace`, so the body of your while loop would look lile:

```
std::cout <<a<<" "<<b<<" "<<c<<" "<<d<<" "<<e<<" "<<f<<" "<<g<<" ";
std::replace( h.begin(), h.end(), '_', ' ' );
std::cout<<h<<"\n";
```

(make sure to include `algorithm`)

We now have all our entires printed!

To directly answer your original question, I'm guessing the file doesn't exist.

```
std::ifstream infile("text.txt");
if(!infile.is_open()) {
     std::cout<<"Couldn't find file";
     return 0;
}
// ..
```

Comment: Thank you! So what if there is one line that does not have a name for that person, and a town, just those other six variables. I just found out in my text file.

Comment: If any one of them are missing you're going to have issues. Perhaps move the less important reading calls (`infile>>x`) outside of the while loop to allow them to gracefully fail. This way it won't crash when things are missing and such. Although this does mean you'll have to validate the input you get later on to be valid.